# Json to CSV using Python and pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv

I'm trying to convert this JSON to CSV. I have tried many ways but without success, I have converted other JSONs but no one with this structure. I'd like to extract only the headers and values.

The best approach that I have was with this code but still did not get a tabular CSV file.

```
import json
import pandas
  
  
def read_json(filename: str) -> dict:
  
    try:
        with open(filename, "r") as f:
            data = json.loads(f.read())
    except:
        raise Exception(f"Reading {filename} file encountered an error")
  
    return data
  
  
def create_dataframe(data: list) -> pandas.DataFrame:
  
    # Declare an empty dataframe to append records
    dataframe = pandas.DataFrame()
  
    # Looping through each record
    for d in data:
          
        # Normalize the column levels
        record = pandas.json_normalize(d)
          
        # Append it to the dataframe 
        dataframe = dataframe.append(record, ignore_index=False)
  
    return dataframe
  
  
def main():
    # Read the JSON file as python dictionary 
    data = read_json(filename="response.json")
  
    # Generate the dataframe for the array items in 
    # details key 
    dataframe = create_dataframe(data=data['values'])
  
    # Renaming columns of the dataframe 
    print("Normalized Columns:", dataframe.columns.to_list())
  
    dataframe.rename(columns={
        "results.school": "school",
        "results.high_school": "high_school",
        "results.graduation": "graduation",
        "education.graduation.major": "grad_major",
        "education.graduation.minor": "grad_minor"
    }, inplace=True)
  
    print("Renamed Columns:", dataframe.columns.to_list())
  
    # Convert dataframe to CSV
    dataframe.to_csv("details.csv", index=True)
  
  
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

has someone had a similar issue?

Thank you.

The Json file

```
{
    "headers": [
        "Warehouse",
        "Days in Date",
        "SKU's",
        "Stock minimo",
        "Stock disponible",
        "Nivel de servcio"
    ],
    "metadata": [
        {
            "jaql": {
                "datatype": "text",
                "column": "Warehouse",
                "merged": true,
                "dim": "[BaseVHS_F41021VHS.Warehouse]",
                "title": "Warehouse",
                "table": "BaseVHS_F41021VHS"
            },
            "field": {
                "index": 0,
                "id": "[BaseVHS_F41021VHS.Warehouse]"
            },
            "handlers": [],
            "panel": "rows"
        },
        {
            "jaql": {
                "datatype": "datetime",
                "level": "days",
                "column": "Date_str",
                "merged": true,
                "dim": "[BaseVHS_F41021VHS.Date_str (Calendar)]",
                "title": "Days in Date",
                "table": "BaseVHS_F41021VHS"
            },
            "field": {
                "index": 1,
                "id": "[BaseVHS_F41021VHS.Date (Calendar)]_days"
            },
            "hierarchies": [
                "calendar",
                "calendar - weeks"
            ],
            "handlers": [
                {}
            ],
            "format": {
                "mask": {
                    "months": "MM/yyyy",
                    "weeks": "ww yyyy",
                    "minutes": "HH:mm",
                    "quarters": "yyyy Q",
                    "days": "shortDate",
                    "isdefault": true,
                    "years": "yyyy"
                }
            },
            "panel": "rows"
        },
        {
            "jaql": {
                "agg": "count",
                "datatype": "numeric",
                "column": "NJDE",
                "dim": "[BaseVHS_F41021VHS.NJDE]",
                "title": "SKU's",
                "table": "BaseVHS_F41021VHS"
            },
            "field": {
                "index": 2,
                "id": "[BaseVHS_F41021VHS.NJDE]_count"
            },
            "handlers": [
                {},
                {}
            ],
            "format": {
                "color": {
                    "color": "transparent",
                    "type": "color"
                },
                "mask": {
                    "b": true,
                    "t": true,
                    "decimals": "auto",
                    "separated": true,
                    "isdefault": true,
                    "type": "number"
                }
            },
            "disabled": false,
            "panel": "measures"
        },
        {
            "jaql": {
                "context": {
                    "[7377E-BFD]": {
                        "agg": "sum",
                        "datatype": "numeric",
                        "column": "ROP",
                        "dim": "[BaseVHS_F41021VHS.ROP]",
                        "title": "Total ROP",
                        "table": "BaseVHS_F41021VHS"
                    }
                },
                "formula": "[7377E-BFD]",
                "type": "measure",
                "title": "Stock minimo"
            },
            "field": {
                "index": 3,
                "id": "[7377E-BFD]"
            },
            "handlers": [
                {},
                {}
            ],
            "format": {
                "color": {
                    "color": "transparent",
                    "type": "color"
                },
                "mask": {
                    "b": true,
                    "t": true,
                    "decimals": "auto",
                    "separated": true,
                    "isdefault": true,
                    "type": "number"
                }
            },
            "panel": "measures"
        },
        {
            "jaql": {
                "context": {
                    "[1BD66-B0A]": {
                        "agg": "sum",
                        "datatype": "numeric",
                        "column": "Qty_SOH",
                        "dim": "[BaseVHS_F41021VHS.Qty_SOH]",
                        "title": "Total Qty_SOH",
                        "table": "BaseVHS_F41021VHS"
                    },
                    "[D2436-DE3]": {
                        "datatype": "numeric",
                        "column": "Qty_SOH",
                        "dim": "[BaseVHS_F41021VHS.Qty_SOH]",
                        "title": "Qty SOH",
                        "table": "BaseVHS_F41021VHS"
                    }
                },
                "formula": "[1BD66-B0A]",
                "type": "measure",
                "title": "Stock disponible"
            },
            "field": {
                "index": 4,
                "id": "[1BD66-B0A]"
            },
            "handlers": [
                {},
                {}
            ],
            "format": {
                "color": {
                    "color": "transparent",
                    "type": "color"
                },
                "mask": {
                    "b": true,
                    "t": true,
                    "decimals": "auto",
                    "separated": true,
                    "isdefault": true,
                    "type": "number"
                }
            },
            "panel": "measures"
        },
        {
            "jaql": {
                "context": {
                    "[8679B-A2B]": {
                        "agg": "avg",
                        "datatype": "numeric",
                        "column": "Column",
                        "dim": "[BaseVHS_F41021VHS.Column]",
                        "title": "Average Column",
                        "table": "BaseVHS_F41021VHS"
                    }
                },
                "formula": "[8679B-A2B]",
                "type": "measure",
                "title": "Nivel de servcio"
            },
            "field": {
                "index": 5,
                "id": "[8679B-A2B]"
            },
            "handlers": [
                {},
                {}
            ],
            "format": {
                "color": {
                    "color": "transparent",
                    "type": "color"
                },
                "mask": {
                    "decimals": "auto",
                    "percent": true
                }
            },
            "panel": "measures"
        }
    ],
    "datasource": {
        "revisionId": "TBD",
        "fullname": "LocalHost/VHS"
    },
    "processingInfo": {
        "cacheType": "none",
        "cacheTime": "2022-06-15T15:40:38.275Z"
    },
    "translationInfo": {
        "translationServiceProvider": "TranslationService",
        "isTranslationFallback": false,
        "isQueryFallback": false
    },
    "values": [
        [
            {
                "data": "    SGBELRAY",
                "text": "    SGBELRAY"
            },
            {
                "data": "2022-06-15 10:24:32.000000",
                "text": "2022-06-15 10:24:32.000000"
            },
            {
                "data": 94.0,
                "text": "94"
            },
            {
                "data": 1018.0,
                "text": "1018"
            },
            {
                "data": 3.0,
                "text": "3"
            },
            {
                "data": 0.18085106382978725,
                "text": "0.180851063829787"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "data": "    SGFERRET",
                "text": "    SGFERRET"
            },
            {
                "data": "2022-06-15 10:24:32.000000",
                "text": "2022-06-15 10:24:32.000000"
            },
            {
                "data": 576.0,
                "text": "576"
            },
            {
                "data": 64505.0,
                "text": "64505"
            },
            {
                "data": 623498.6,
                "text": "623498.6"
            },
            {
                "data": 0.8663194444444444,
                "text": "0.866319444444444"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: can you provide an example of the desired output? At the moment we can only guess what you want to achieve exactly...

Comment: Edo, thank you for your post. next time I'll elaborate on the question better. Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to extract only headers and values, you can pass it to a dataframe:

```py
import json
import pandas as pd

data = json.loads(open('your_file.json').read())
print(data['headers']))

>> ['Warehouse',
   'Days in Date',
   "SKU's",
   'Stock minimo',
   'Stock disponible',
   'Nivel de servcio']

print(data['values'])

>> [[{'data': '    SGBELRAY', 'text': '    SGBELRAY'},
 {'data': '2022-06-15 10:24:32.000000', 'text': '2022-06-15 10:24:32.000000'},
 {'data': 94.0, 'text': '94'},
 {'data': 1018.0, 'text': '1018'},
 {'data': 3.0, 'text': '3'},
 {'data': 0.18085106382978725, 'text': '0.180851063829787'}],
[{'data': '    SGFERRET', 'text': '    SGFERRET'},
 {'data': '2022-06-15 10:24:32.000000', 'text': '2022-06-15 10:24:32.000000'},
 {'data': 576.0, 'text': '576'},
 {'data': 64505.0, 'text': '64505'},
 {'data': 623498.6, 'text': '623498.6'},
 {'data': 0.8663194444444444, 'text': '0.866319444444444'}]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data['values'], columns=data['headers']).applymap(lambda x: x['data'])

df.to_csv('your_file.csv', index=False)
```

And you will get:

[image]

Let me know, if this is not exactly what you need.

Comment: You read my mind that is exactly what I need and you solved it with a few lines of code. I really appreciate your help. Thank you!